# Delete charts from range

Tags: vba, excel

I have two charts in a range of cells that I am trying to delete with VBA. Rather than deleting the charts, it iterates through a bunch of times without doing anything at all. This is what I have tried so far.

```
For Each ChartObjects In Range(Cells(i + 3, 12), Cells(i + 19, 50))
     ChartObjects.Delete
Next ChartObjects
```

Comment: ChartObjects cannot be assigned to Range Objects. You'll need to do something like check if the `ChartArea.Top` or `ChartArea.Left` or `ChartArea.Width` is within the same coordinates as the same for the range. Or you could use some type of dynamic naming for the charts and check `Chart.Name` property to delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the TopLeftCell property of the ChartObject to check whether the cell under the top left corner of the chart falls within the range...

```
Dim oChrtObj As ChartObject

For Each oChrtObj In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
     If Not Application.Intersect(oChrtObj.TopLeftCell, _
        Range(Cells(i + 3, 12), Cells(i + 19, 50))) Is Nothing Then
            oChrtObj.Delete
     End If
Next oChrtObj
```

Note, though, you can also delete all charts using a single line...

```
activesheet.chartobjects.delete
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Clever. I just had to add an "s" every time you had just ChartObject.

Comment: Actually, for clarity, since ChartObject is a data type, the name of the For Each control variable should differ from the name ChartObject.  So I've amended the code accordingly..

Comment: Hi, @Domenic! What if the chart is located, for example in the Range("H7"), or Cells(rowNo, 8)? ```rowNo``` is dynamic, so finding the range where the chart is like this is crucial! Thank you!